# sum values in excel that are not equal too - multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create a boolean array in a new column that specifies if multiple criteria are fulfilled in multiple other columns or not. It works, however if I want to check whether a value is NOT present instead of IS present, the formula fails if you use <>, as I did in the example below.

How would I properly do this? So I want to find all rows (and put a 0 and 1 in them) for which criteria 1 and criteria 2 is fullfilled, with criteria 2 being not equal to neither Vastgoed ongeschikt voor huisvesting nor Andere activiteit.

```
> =(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Surface_libre!$H$1:$H$1000; {"Staatseigendom"};0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Surface_libre!$I$1:$I$1000;{"<>Vastgoed
> ongeschikt voor huisvesting";"<>Andere activiteit"};0)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I believe when your comparison is to an array the return will be an array, which may be causing the formula to not work. You may need to wrap that formula with an aggregation formula.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use BYROW, like this (supposing your data are in columns A and B)

```
=BYROW($A$1:$B$18,LAMBDA(r,N(AND(INDEX(r,1,1)="Staatseigendom",INDEX(r,1,2)<>"Vastgoed ongeschikt voor huisvesting",INDEX(r,1,2)<>"Andere activiteit"))))
```

[image]

If you don't have BYROW, then try this (supposing data in A and B):

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$18,{"Staatseigendom"},0))*ISNA(MATCH($B$1:$B$18,{"Vastgoed ongeschikt voor huisvesting"},0))*ISNA(MATCH($B$1:$B$18,{"Andere activiteit"},0))
```

[image]